# Conditional C++ Class Member Definition

Tags: c++, class

I'd like to define two variations of a class depending on a template parameter in a C++ class. (I'm using C++17.)

For example, if the template parameter `bool flag` is true, I'd like the class to have a member:

```
Class1 foo;
```

and if `flag` if false

```
Class2 bar;
```

The class definition would also have some logic variation and use either `foo` or `bar`. I could implement this using inheritance but I'm exploring if there's another approach. It seems that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional may be helpful but I'm not sure. I could also just have both members and just use one of them in any given object, but that seems wasteful and there must be a better way. Note that I don't necessarily need to name the members differently if a particular solution would simply allow me to swap out the class but not the name (perhaps with conditional?).

Comment: You can use template specialisation.

Comment: While you describe and ask for help with a solution, what problem is this solution supposed to actually solve? What is the *original* problem? Why do you need to use different members depending on a `bool` template? Perhaps there could be other solutions?

Comment: And why don't you provide `Class1` or `Class2` as a template argument instead? Why do you need to use different names for the member variable? And do `Class1` and `Class2` have the same or similar interface? Are `Class1` and `Class2` related in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can live with the same member name for both versions, then it is trivial:

```
template <bool flag>
struct Foo {
    std::conditional_t<flag, Class1, Class2> foo;
};
```

Comment: How can OP call (or construct) that member object and pass it the bool?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf the member does not need the bool, it will be of either type. Both types just need to have the same interface, in the duck-typing sense.

Comment: I still don't know how to use this, I never seen it. So If an outsider creates an instance of the boss class, where do they pass the condition `flag`? And how do the boss class know to either access foo.`Class1` stuff or foo.`Class2` stuff?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf That would really depend on what the two classes are and how (if at all) they are related. But one could use `if constexpr (flag) { /* use Class2 members */ } else { /* use Class1 members */ }`. Not pretty or as good as if the two classes have the same interface, but still possible to do.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am still confused :D Maybe a usage example for the proposed answer would help. OP has a class `X` and would like a member to be either `Class1` or `Class2` based on some flag. Now, if user creates `X`, do they pass it the flag? If yes, how? in the constructor?

Comment: @Quentin thanks! I think this works for me nicely. What about a situation where we only want to add a member of a class if the `flag` is true and not have any member at all otherwise?

Comment: @KhalilKhalaf I think it would be something like `new Foo<true>()` or `new Foo<false>()`

Comment: @Kulluk007 removing or renaming the member would require more involved tricks, such as inheritance as you mentioned in your question. I'd probably just use an empty dummy type for that branch and be done with it in the general case.

Comment: @Quentin got it -- so something like `std::tuple<>()` as an empty type? Or is there an even more idiomatic empty type these days?

Comment: @Kulluk007 `struct empty {};` ;)